# Are you required to make an http request when trying to use Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, django, chart.js

I followed a tutorial video that showed how to set up Chart.js with Django, using Jquery and API function calls to a page on my site. However, I don't need to make these function calls to get the data, as the data are associated with my objects themselves. When I get rid of the http function call and just write the code instead, my graphs don't show up. Is the http format required? A working version I have is:

```
            <script> 
            var endpoint = ''/api/chart/data/'';

            fetch(endpoint, {
                method: "GET",
            }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(
                data => {
                console.log('Success:', data);
                graph_data = {...}
                var ctx{{ forloop.counter }} = document.getElementById("myChart{{ forloop.counter }}");

                var myChart =  new Chart(ctx{{ forloop.counter }}, graph_data); 
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log("Error:")
                    console.log(error);
                });

                        
        </script>
        <div style="width: 60%; float:left;">
            <canvas id= "myChart{{ forloop.counter }}" style = "padding-bottom: 9px;"></canvas>
        </div>
```

Could this instead just be:

```
                console.log('Success:', data);
                graph_data = {...}
                var ctx{{ forloop.counter }} = document.getElementById("myChart{{ forloop.counter }}");

                var myChart =  new Chart(ctx{{ forloop.counter }}, graph_data);
```

```
    <div style="width: 60%; float:left;">
        <canvas id= "myChart{{ forloop.counter }}" style = "padding-bottom: 9px;"></canvas>
    </div>
```

The error I am getting is

```
Chart.min.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at Object.acquireContext (Chart.min.js:14)
    at new t.Controller (Chart.min.js:11)
    at new t (Chart.min.js:12)
    at (index):616
```

Comment: The http call is not necessary to use the library or create a chart. You can load the data from an object but does your data load BEFORE the chart is initialised ?

Comment: @ZombieChowder I've edited the post to show where I set graph_data. As far as I understand the variable is set before the chart is loaded. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is it. Point your `graph_data = {...}` to your data and it should work without the http request (if you do have the data without making a call).

Comment: @ZombieChowder what do you mean by point it to your data? Right now the data is where the ... is.

Comment: well you said your data is not loaded from an http request. That means that is stored in another variable, point the `graph_data` to that variable.

Comment: @ZombieChowder well i have the data that i need for the chart inside of those brackets right now and then i just use graph_data in my chart call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP call is not part of anything related to Chart.js.

The reason why it's not working is you're calling "getElementById" before the DOM element you're looking for has been loaded.

The reason why it works when you are using the fetch call is that while you are making the HTTP request, you are giving the DOM time to load your canvas.

It's usually best to wait for your whole DOM to load before running any javascript.

### Solution

Move the script tag to the bottom of the page
OR
Add "defer" to your script tag  which will tell the browser to start running the javascript after the DOMContent has been parsed.

Comment: Moving the script after the canvas tag worked. Thanks!